# One line code from Objective-C to Swift 4

Tags: objective-c, swift

Here I have some Objective-C source code:

```
MPushNotificationConfiguration *configuration = [[MPushNotificationConfiguration alloc] init];  
configuration.types = MPushAuthorizationOptionsBadge | MPushAuthorizationOptionsSound | MPushAuthorizationOptionsAlert;
[MobPush setupNotification:configuration];
```

Now I want to change it into Swift and I tried as follow:

```
var configuration = MPushNotificationConfiguration()
configuration.types = .alert | .badge | .sound
MobPush.setupNotification(configuration)
```

But it reads:

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

I tried like this:

```
var configuration = MPushNotificationConfiguration()
configuration.types = MPushAuthorizationOptions.alert | MPushAuthorizationOptions.badge | MPushAuthorizationOptions.sound
MobPush.setupNotification(configuration)
```

It reads:

> Cannot convert value of type 'MPushAuthorizationOptions' to expected argument type 'UInt8'

I had checked some help documentation but nothing helped. I started with Swift 3, then Swift 4, and I know a little about Objective-C. How swift express like "|" in Objective-C?

Comment: I think, configuration.type need an array of parameters such as [.alert, .badge, .sound]

Comment: The term `oc` is not widely used, and even though I have years of Objective-C experience I did not know what your post was about from the subject. The common abbreviation is objc. I suggest editing your question - especially the title.

Comment: Thanks very much for your editing. I would keep in mind :)  @Duncan C

Comment: I would try it soon, thanks a lot for your comment :) @a.afanasiev

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MPushAuthorizationOptions` here likely conforms to `OptionSet` when bridged to swift, allowing you to specify multiple options.

In Objective-C, you would OR all the values to combine the bits. In Swift, there is a special syntax.

According to the docs for [`OptionSet`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optionset),

> #### Using an Option Set Type
>
> When you need to create an instance of an option set, assign one of the type’s static members to your variable or constant. Alternatively, to create an option set instance with multiple members, **assign an array literal with multiple static members of the option set**. To create an empty instance, assign an empty array literal to your variable.

So you should do:

```
configuration.types = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your kindly reply. I would try it :)